# How to solve the integral $\int_{0}^{t} X^2 \, (dX)^2$ for a stochastic process $X$?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, stochastic-processes

$$ \int_{0}^{t} X^2 \, (dX)^2 $$

$X$ being a stochastic process, and I just stuck with this integral.

---

[<sup>Click here to view the original source.</sup>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/51xEb.png)

Comment: What do you mean by "solve" it?  For most stochastic processes, there isn't really a way to simplify that integral.  Without more context, I don't think there's much that can be done here.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level. Please take moment to give [this posting](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/9340) a read to learn how to ask a good question.